# Testing Web Chat in Azure

Tags: botframework

I am new to the process and was hoping to get some help with finalizing testing for Q&A bot in Azure. I updated/published my knowledge base and now I am at the last step, testing Web Chat in Azure but bot is not responding.

Comment: Here is what I have done so far 1) connected QnA maker to my bot 2) tested my knowledge base in QnA Maker 3) Updated my host keys in Azura. How can i check my connection from Azure to QnA maker, maybe something is missing and that is the reason why Bot is not responding?

Comment: Can you post what error you are getting in the dev console when you try to test in Web Chat? Also, have you updated the QnAEndpointHostName under the application settings for the bot on Azure?